# How do I deal with subscribed functions dispatching actions in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Action A calls reducer function that modifies the state. As a result, Function A gets called because it is subscribed to that part of the state of the store. Function A then dispatches Action B. A reducer function gets called and further modifies the state. Function B gets called because it is subscribed to the store and dispatches Action A.

```
// subscribed to changes in state resulting from actionA
counter = 0
let prevStateForA
function A(newState) {

    if newState === prevStateForA:
        return
    prevStateForA = newState

    if counter < 3:
        counter++
        dispatch(actionB())    
}


// subscribed to changes in state resulting from actionB
let prevStateForB
function B(newState) {

    if newState === prevStateForB:
        return
    prevStateForB = newState

    dispatch(actionA())
}

dispatch(actionA())
```

The problem I have is that the subscription process looks like this:

```
// from https://github.com/ivantsov/redux-subscriber
export function subscribe(key, cb) {
    if (subscribers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        subscribers[key].push(cb);
    } else {
        subscribers[key] = [cb];
    }

    // return "unsubscribe" function
    return function() {
        subscribers[key] = subscribers[key].filter(s => s !== cb);
    };
}


function initSubscriber(store) {
    let prevState = store.getState();

    store.subscribe(() => {

        const newState = store.getState();

        Object.keys(subscribers).forEach(key => {
            if (get(prevState, key) !== get(newState, key)) {
                subscribers[key].forEach(cb => {
                    cb(newState);
                });
            }
        });

        prevState = newState;
    });

    return subscribe;
}
```

When `actionA()` is dispatched in `B()`, it calls the `subscribe` function in `initSubscriber`. It then calls `B()` again because `prevState` has not yet been updated with the previous `newState`.

Eventually, this makes my program run into problems. I was originally able to ignore it by having a `prevState` variable for each subscribed function but now, the `newState` variable passed into each function is behind the `prevState` variable saved.

How can I fix this logical issue?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete description of your use case?  _Why_ are you manually subscribing to the store?  Typically this is handled by the React-Redux APIs.  What sorts of updates actually need to happen here? What kinds of actions are you dispatching based on state changes? My overall thought is that you should find a different way to architect this entirely, but I'd need to know some specifics to give better advice.

Comment: I am attempting to make a game with React and Redux and have some logic outside a React Component. I read in a few places that using a wrapper function like this is generally OK. I can think of a few ways to refactor this to reduce Redux actions, but I was wondering if that was necessary and if anyone was using Redux in a similar way.

Comment: Can you update the question with a couple _specific_ examples that demonstrate the kinds of things you're trying to do?